# how to let my android device act like a web server

Tags: android, webserver, video-streaming

i want to stream my videos stored on my android device on the pc (vlc ...) 
So i need to create an app that allow me to use my android as a web server so that i can send http requests from the pc to get the video.
i made it with [WebDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.webdroid&hl=en) but i was told to avoid using ready apps, so i wanted to know how to let my android device act like a web server without using any app ( using simple code )